# GridView adapter on Android (error)

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

i get an error when i'm calling the adapter:

in my main class i have:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.discotecas_layout);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    discotecaslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
```

and in background i have on postexecute this:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
      pDialog.dismiss();
      gridView.setAdapter(new Gridadapter(activity.this, imagenes));
      // updating UI from Background Thread
   }
```

and my adapter is this one:

```
public class Gridadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Bitmap[] imagenes;

    public Gridadapter(Context c, Bitmap[] imagenes) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.imagenes = imagenes;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imagenes.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imagenes[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

what i'm doing wrong? i think it's something with the adapter but i don't know what

the error is:

```
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(TabDiscotecas.java:192)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(TabDiscotecas.java:1)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-14 18:32:20.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    ... 4 more
01-14 18:32:20.399: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cd53000 size:1216512
01-14 18:32:20.399: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cadc000 size:4096
01-14 18:32:20.399: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6d98e000 size:1216512
01-14 18:32:20.399: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cbfd000 size:4096
01-14 18:32:20.399: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6e2af000 size:1216512
01-14 18:32:20.399: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cbff000 size:4096
01-14 18:32:20.409: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6d052000 size:8355840
01-14 18:32:20.409: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cb3e000 size:4096
01-14 18:32:20.409: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6dab7000 size:8355840
01-14 18:32:20.409: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cbfe000 size:4096
01-14 18:32:20.409: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6e3d8000 size:8355840
01-14 18:32:20.409: D/qdmemalloc(16322): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cc26000 size:4096
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322): Activity com.example.apparty.MainActivity    has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41b0c038 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.apparty.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41b0c038 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:394)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(TabDiscotecas.java:142)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas.onCreate(TabDiscotecas.java:81)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2298)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:759)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at com.example.apparty.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
01-14 18:32:20.439: E/WindowManager(16322):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `gridView.setAdapter(new Gridadapter(ActivityName.this, imagenes));`

Comment: post complete stacktrace. why did you not post the complete stacktrace ? what made you think it was not relevant ?

Comment: apparently imagenes is null. you probably just didn't instanciate it

Comment: i update it, yes in that moment i take out when i instanciate the images for try, now here is the real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesn't look like an error with your adapter specifically, looks like there's an issue with the loading of your images, since the last line of your error comes from

```
com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(TabDiscotecas.java:232)
```

might want to check there first, if the loading is failing, then the image array you are passing to the adapter is likely null

Comment: maybe the problem is with context... how should i pass?

Comment: still says that you have a null error in your doInBackground method - you need to make sure that you are downloading files correctly

Comment: the error was than i don't initialice the drawable array u.u thx a lot!